# Using incremented integers to repeatedly create objects

Tags: c#, grid, integer, picturebox

I want to create a grid of picture boxes on a form and name them: "sqr" +  i + "_" + j where i = number of the square horizontally, and j = number of the square vertically so I can easily identify each square and know where it is on the form.

Currently, I'm doing it manually one by one, copying and pasting the code and modifying it for each square but I have to believe there is an easier way of doing this. I'm open to all suggestions as I am relatively (6 months) new to C#.

I imagine the code would look something like this, at least, this is how I want it to work in theory:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
  currentSpawnLocationX = currentSpawnLocationX + 40;
  currentSpawnLocationY = 0;
  for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
  {
    PictureBox sqri_j = new PictureBox();
    sqri_j.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(currentSpawnLocationX, currentSpawnLocationY);
    sqri_j.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
    currentSpawnLocationY = currentSpawnLocationY + 40;
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated. If it can be re-done in a completely different way and I'm doing it all wrong, I would love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a collection of some form - in this case, a 2-dimensional array is probably the most appropriate...

Comment: Are you having a problem with something in particular? Like setting the `.Name` property on the picture box or accessing a specific picture box at index (i, j) after the fact?

Comment: I would like to be able to name the picture boxes sqr1_1, sqr1_2, sqr1_3 etc using the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said a 2-dimensional array is your best option.

Would be something like this :

```
PictureBox[,] sqr = new PictureBox[20,20];

for (i = 1; i <= sqr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    currentSpawnLocationX = currentSpawnLocationX + 40;
    currentSpawnLocationY = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= sqr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        sqr[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        sqr[i, j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(currentSpawnLocationX, currentSpawnLocationY);
        sqr[i, j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
        currentSpawnLocationY = currentSpawnLocationY + 40;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT for what you ask in the comment:** 
For this I would create an array with pre-loaded resources, like this (with a resource naming convention):

```
Image[,] images = new Image[20,20];

for (i = 1; i <= images.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= images.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
         images = (Image)Tileset.ResourceManager.getObject(string.format("image_resource_name_{0}_{1}", i ,j));                          
    }
}
```

This way you could init your picturebox like this :

```
sqr[i, j].Image = images[i, j]
```

You can easily merge this with the picturebox initialisation of the original answer.

Comment: That's great, thanks! And the source code will be useful to use as a basis and edit.

Comment: While this is relatively fresh, and I don't want to start a completely separate thread for a related topic, is there a way I can access a png in a resource file using an array of strings? ... 
      sqr[i, j].Image = Tileset.img[i, j]; ... 
"Tileset" is the name of the resource file. "img" is an array of literal strings matching the names of the PNGs in "Tileset".

Comment: I wish Stack Overflow would let me upvote you... Anyway, thank you! I'll try implementing this right now.